# scrapy shell unable to open response in firefox

Tags: python, firefox, scrapy

I had some trouble using firefox today, so I removed it then reinstalled it and it worked fine, however, I use as default browser but I can't open any scrapy shell `view(response)` in it, although the temp file is created and I can open it using Chrome.

```
/snap/firefox/253/bin/desktop-launch: line 177: /home/madboy/snap/firefox/common/.config/user-dirs.dirs.md5sum: No such file or directory
/snap/firefox/253/bin/desktop-launch: line 177: /home/madboy/snap/firefox/common/.config/user-dirs.locale.md5sum: No such file or directory
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: can you share what happens when you `view(response)` does it give any errors?

Comment: @wishmaster added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem may occur because of the compatibility issue with the 64-bit machine when one installs 32-bit software that requires canberra-gtk-module. You can install it like this

`sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module`.